# angularJS: ng-pattern for multiple matches of pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

It seems like a common way to validate values that are comma-separated is to split them into an array, then perform the regEx match on each member. However, I would like to take advantage of Angular's instant validation and perform this match in the view.

My regEx:

```
^\d{5}?,*$
```

works perfectly on the first match, but I'm at a loss as to how to ask it to check for this pattern n-times.

Form Code:

```
        <form id="zipCodeForm" name="zipCodeForm"  ng-submit="submit()" >
            <input id="zipCodeInput" ng-model="text" name="text" type="text"
            required ng-pattern="/^\d{5}?,*$/" > </input>

            <input id="zipSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary"></input>
            <div class="alert alert-info formatguide" ng-show="zipCodeForm.text.$dirty && zipCodeForm.text.$invalid">
               Enter Comma Separated 5-Digit Zip Codes ex.(11111,22222,33333)
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Just a heads up. This `\d{5}?` syntax does not mean optionally find 5 digits, it means find 5 digits. This `,*` means optionally find multiple consecutive commas.

Comment: @sln Correct, and that actually is the validation I want in this point, Angular handles a blank submission with the "required" attribute on the form, and the 5 digits is not optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know how many zip codes, but want at least one, then this
`^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})*$`

If you know how many, use this
`^\d{5}(?:,\d{5}){how many - 1}$`

*EDIT*  -  The two regexes explained.

```
 ^                    # Begining of string
 \d{5}                # followed by 5 digits
 (?:                  # Cluster group
      ,                    # a literal comma
      \d{5}                # followed by 5 digits
 )*                   # End Cluster group, optionally do many times
 $                    # End of string

 # ---------------------------------------------------------

 ^                    # Begining of string
 \d{5}                # followed by 5 digits
 (?:                  # Cluster group
      ,                    # a literal comma
      \d{5}                # followed by 5 digits
 ){3}                 # End Cluster group, do exactly 3 times
 $                    # End of string
```

Comment: Is using the (), non-remembering match syntax standard form for checking regEx against n-number of matches? I've never encountered this particular need before.

Comment: @Thomas Murphy - Added regex explaination. I don't know angularjs, I'm assuming the regex matches a data string, and does not have a tertiary matching with a form template to the data.

Comment: Great expansion, the cluster group makes things a lot more clear.

Comment: @Thomas Murphy - Thanks. I use `RegexFomat4` from ([here](http://www.regexformat.com)). With just a button click, it goes back and forth from expanssion to compressed. Makes maintainance a breeze.